# tulips already install but still attribute error come?

Tags: python

import tulips
tulips.perceived_color(m11, time_ind=0, fig_size=(8,6))
plt.show()

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
1 import tulips
----> 2 tulips.perceived_color(m11, time_ind=0, fig_size=(8,6))
3 plt.show()

AttributeError: module 'tulips' has no attribute 'perceived_color'

Comment: Please link the documentation of the package you are using, and format your code and the output with fenced code blocks. The error is telling you that it found the `tulips` module, but cannot find `perceived_color` in it. Are you sure it should be accessed by `tulips.perceived_color`?

Comment: yes, perceived color function not run.